# Add cookies to request in Angular and set it on back side on .NET Core 5

Tags: angular, .net-core, cookies

I have in my app Angular interceptor and there I set the header.

```
const clonedReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')),
            withCredentials: true,
        });
```

As you can see I set `withCredentials: true` but I don`t see any cookies in request

[image]

My cokies look like this in browser

[image]

If I cant do that on front side, why I cant set cookies on back side. I do it by this way. First StartUp

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>
            {
                p.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
```

and in Configure `app.UseCors("AllowAll");`

Than in my Controller before return Ok();

```
Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value", new CookieOptions()
        {
            Path = "/",
        });
```

When my .NET Core app was monolit with Angular it had worked. But when I separated for two projects I couldn`t to manage the cookies on both sides. How I can add cookies to request and set it on backend?

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar implementation and is working fine, i hope my code is helpful for you
interceptor:

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private jwtAuth: JwtAuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    var token = this.jwtAuth.token || this.jwtAuth.getJwtToken();

    var changedReq;

    if (token) {

      changedReq = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      });

    } else {

      changedReq = req;
      
    }
    return next.handle(changedReq);
  }
}
```

in dotnet controller

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserForLoginDto UserForLoginDto)
        {
            var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(UserForLoginDto.Username.ToLower(), UserForLoginDto.Password);

            if (userFromRepo == null)
                return Unauthorized();

            var claims = new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username)
                };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var permissionList = GetCurrentRolPermission(UserForLoginDto.Username);
            return Ok(new
            {
                token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
                permissionList = permissionList
            });
        }
```

i dont set the cookies in the backend i return an OK with a json with 2 properties and then i use that properties to save the credentials on localStorage in angular

Comment: Sorry, but I need to use cookies with backend

Comment: Ok, if you do not resolve it already try to upload a sample to github i maybe i can check the code online. greetings :)